# Can I "fix" wrong Resharper annotations?

Tags: annotations, resharper

I love Resharper, but sometimes it gives incorrect warnings, probably because the built-in annotations for BCL types are wrong. For instance, in this code:

```
private static string GetDescription(T value)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        ...
```

It gives me a warning on the `if` statement: "Expression is always true". But `Enum.GetName` can return null:

```
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), (DayOfWeek)42); // null
```

I assume this is because there is a `[NotNull]` annotation for `Enum.GetName`. Is there a way to fix that so I don't get the warning?

*Note: I'm using Resharper 5.1; perhaps that issue is fixed in version 6, but I'm not willing to upgrade right now.*

Comment: The problem still happens with ReSharper 6.1.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, really? It's [supposed to be fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-256926) according to their bug tracker...

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I found the solution, in case you're interested (see my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I got it. The built-in annotations are defined in XML files in the Resharper installation directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v5.1\Bin\ExternalAnnotations\` on my machine). The solution is to edit the appropriate file to remove or fix the incorrect annotations.

In the case of `Enum.GetName`, the file to change is `mscorlib\mscorlib.[version].Contracts.xml`. I just commented this annotation:

```
  <member name="M:System.Enum.GetName(System.Type,System.Object)">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
  </member>
```

And restarted Visual Studio, and now the warning is gone :)

Comment: I updated their issue to show it's not fixed. You might update it to show the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to Thomas's answer, they seem to have moved things around in the last couple of years.

For Resharper 8.2.3, the above file now resides in:

`C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny\packages\ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations.8.2.3001\ReSharper\vAny\annotations\.NETFramework\mscorlib\...`

so, if you're trying to do that, you can search that path (or one up, for non `mscorlib` files).