# Why is resharper suggesting that the left operand is never null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Seems like Dialog results return a nullable boolean (**bool?**), so whenever using a return dialog, you should take care of the null option (which I'm yet waiting to see happening ... ).

The above code (VS2012, Resharper 8), suggests that the left operand is never null. Any ideas why?

```
bool? dlg_result = some_window.ShowDialog();
bool some_bool = !dlg_result ?? true; // Resharper suggests this won't happen.
```

Here's a screenshot, easier to see:

[image: screenshot]

Edit:
I've had a look in the resharper files, and it seems like `ShowDialog` won't be null when using it from `CommonDialog` and the `Control`, but it might be null when using it from `Window`. Attaching screenshot.
Will have to dig a bit deeper it seems, since I'm not sure which one I'm using.

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Well, you may look at this answer to see that the cases where ShowDialog returns a null is really specific. In this case, I would say it won't happen : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990109/when-would-showdialog-return-null

Comment: @SonerGönül well, a `bool?` :)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus cheers for the link. I'll use that in conjunction with the "fix" resharper annotation, and see what's up.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper includes a feature called [Code Annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) which provides a mechanism for decorating source code with hints for ReSharper.  For example:

```
[NotNull]
public object Foo()
{
    return null; // Warning: Possible 'null' assignment
}
```

The `NotNull` attribute will instruct ReSharper to issue a Visual Studio warning in the method if it tries to return null.  It will also cause ReSharper to issue the suggestion that a null coalescing operator (`??`) is not necessary because the method return value is never null:

```
Foo() ?? new object; //Causes '??' left operand is never null suggestion
```

ReSharper has additional support for adding [External Annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html) to core .Net code.  This allows these hints to be added to code that ReSharper doesn't control.  (You can also use this if you wanted to add annotation to a 3rd party library).

So to wrap up, it appears ReSharper has annotated `Window.ShowDialog` with `[NotNull]` so even though the return type is nullable, ReSharper "knows" it will never be null and makes the suggestion you are seeing.

Comment: And see [Can I “fix” wrong Resharper annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254845/can-i-fix-wrong-resharper-annotations) for what to do when JetBrains' shipped annotations are wrong.

Comment: Cheers for that. I'll have a look at the annotations "fixing" as well, and update